# Почему не передатся данные в firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase

Собственно создал проект в firebase подключил к приложению делаю так

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); 
        messagesDataBaseReference = database.getReference("message");
        messagesDataBaseReference.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

правила поставил такие

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,  
    ".write": true,  
  }
}
```

но данные не сохраняются в firebase хотел бы понять почему. Можете подсказать как ?
База находится на европейском сервере но в google-services.json адрес сервера указан.

Comment: Попробуйте подключить логирование запроса. Будет проще диагностировать

Comment: @Andrew а как это делается ?

Comment: приблизительно так https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile, так же попробуйте потестировать не на андроиде, а на чистой обертке для работы с базой данных